# How to wait for browser to fully load PDF for printing in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, browser, printing

I'm tryin to code a Solution for printing pdfs one after another with a browser (Chrome) in C#.
How do i Wait the browser to fully load the PDF and after that wait the printer to finish printing?
Or is there even a better solution for that which does it in the background?

I tried to start the process and then wait for several seconds and then print it with ctrl+p. I learned that this is not a rly good solution cause it takes alot of time and is dependend on how big the PDF file is.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestPdf
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process process = new Process();

            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"here is the path for chrome.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"here is the path to pdf file";

            process.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(process.ProcessName + " started = " + process.Start().ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(3999);
            Console.WriteLine("Ctrl P");
            SendKeys.SendWait("^(p)");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("enter");
            SendKeys.SendWait("~");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Process[] chromeInstances = Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome");

            //close all chrome instances
            foreach (Process p in chromeInstances)
            {
                p.Kill();
                Console.WriteLine("Process closed");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("END");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I expected it to print the pdf, which it does but i would like to change my  thread.sleeps to smth more responsive, depending on how fast the pdf is loaded. Also im not rly happy with my solution as it kinda needs my browser to be in the foreground otherwise the "ctrl P" is gettin lost in nirvana.

Edit: I am purposely not using Adobe, cause when i tried it with adobe i was never able to fully close adobe again.

Comment: [Process.WaitForExit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netframework-4.8) should help you

Comment: Well this is part of the solution but not all :/. I need some answer for how to wait till page loaded completely so i can start the print operation.

Comment: you should use the [WebBrowser  Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser?view=netframework-4.8) to handle the browser and to check if the page loaded you can use [DocumentCompleted event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Yes, i thought so too, and tried to use em but somehow didnt manage to handle em right? can u show an example for how to do so?

Comment: It might be useful to take a step back, and review what your overall objective is, since it seems people are having difficulty answering your question. Why is using chrome to print important? Why is coding in C# important?

Comment: Well I'm only using Chrome, cause Adoble is blocking my process.kill requests, thats why I can't ensure closing Adobe, but I can for Chrome. Basically I can replace Chrome if i can ensure printing and closing if needed. I use C# cause im running it in Tools written in C# and as its supposed to be a .dll it should probably be written in the same Language that im refering it to.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example

```
        static WebBrowser webBrowser;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
            NavigateToUrl("stackoverflow.com");
            webBrowser.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser_DocumentCompleted;
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void webBrowser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

           /// Print example but you can do whatever you want here
           /// 
            // Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
            ((WebBrowser)sender).Print();

            // Dispose the WebBrowser now that the task is complete. 
            ((WebBrowser)sender).Dispose();
        }

        private static void NavigateToUrl(String address)
        {
            //
            var uri = GetUriFromAddress(address);
            try
            {
                if (uri != null)
                {
                    /// set uri to the webBrowser object
                    webBrowser.Url = uri;
                    webBrowser.Navigate(uri);
                }
                else
                    return;
            }
            catch (UriFormatException)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

        private static Uri GetUriFromAddress(String address)
        {
            // can accept both HTTP and HTTPS URLs as valid 
            Uri uriResult;
            if (Uri.TryCreate(address, UriKind.Absolute, out uriResult)
                      && (uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps))
                return uriResult;
            else
                return null;          

        }
```

Comment: Yea this is not working, as I am opening a local PDF with the Browser, i'm pretty confused with your answer cause i feel like its the solution for a different problem not mine. To clearify it. I open a PDF with the browser (chrome) and then want to wait until browser fully loaded the local pdf so i can press "ctrl + p" to print it and close it again. My problem is i dont know how to detect when the PDF has finished loading.If i could track that event, i could simpy start printing right that moment.Atm i solve it with a fix time, but i want the "wait time" to adjust to the time it needs to load

Comment: are you loading the from the internal drive?

Comment: yes so basically i open it like this
            `process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\chrome.exe";`
            `process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"C:\pdfFile.pdf";`

Comment: why do u need to open in the browser and not call directly to the PDF file itself? Anyway I don't know if you can do what you want with `Process`

Comment: Because if I open it directly it will use adobe, which then will not close properly cause they want people to buy the full license for stuff like that and then call the API. I dont have the license and I dont plan on gettin it either, thats why I tried this workaround.

Comment: If you are using WinForms you can attach the WebView to the Form and then print from there

Comment: Sadly this is not possible, cause im kinda trying to make it a .dll so I rly need a solution capable to be used as a dll.